# search the value in delimited key value string using regex

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a semicolon delimited key value pairs. How can I search the value by giving the key .I need this for Mule soft expression. I know this can be done in java .I am looking for only Regex to find the string.

Example:

> abc=123;bcd=345;efg=567

If I search for **abc** it should give me **123**

How can I do this in Regex? It should ignore/trim the trailing white spaces in the value.

Comment: can we do this just with Regex ? can we use hardcoded string in Regex some thing like "get me the string between abc= and ;" ?

Comment: I got the answer

Comment: (?<=\abc=)(.*?)(?=\;)

Answer (score 0):

Steps to Do this :

- First split the string into token array using `;` as delimiter
- Second for each  token split it with `=`, Here first item is the key and the second one is the value
- Third put these key value into `HashMap`.
- Get the value of key using `map.get()` method

Example :

```
String data = "abc=123;bcd=345;efg=567";

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String keyValue : data.split(";")) {
    String[] temp = keyValue.split("=", 2);
    map.put(temp[0], temp[1].trim());
}

System.out.println(map.get("abc"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**JAVA**

Is not necessary use `regex`, you can do that using `split()` method from the `String` class. Here an example using `streams`:

```
String line = "abc=123;bcd=345;efg=567";
HashMap<String, String> map = Arrays
    .stream(line.split(";")) //------------> splits the string where a semicolon is found
    .map(val -> val.split("=", 2)) // -----> splits and convert them to the map
    .collect(Collectors
        .toMap(curKey -> curKey[0], // -------> retrieves the key
               curVal -> curVal[1].trim(),//--> retrieves values by trimming white spaces
               (a, b) -> b, HashMap::new));//-> assigns the values

System.out.println(map.get("abc"));
```

**Output:** `123`

---

**REGEX:**

Using regex you can retrieve the value with the following expression:

```
([\\w]+)?=([\\w\\s]+)?;?
```

**For example:**

```
String line = "abc=123;bcd=345;efg=567";
String search = "abc"; // -------------------------> key to search the chain
String regex = "([\\w]+)?=([\\w\\s]+)?;?"; // -----> regex expression
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
    if (search.equals(matcher.group(1))){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2).trim()); // ----> Gets the value
    }
}
```

**Output:** `123`

Comment: can we do this just with Regex ? can we use hardcoded string in Regex some thing like "get me the string between abc= and ;" ?